# Подключить библиотеку ws2_32.lib

Tags: c++, borland-c++

Делаю прогу, которая должна парсить сайт.
При использовании конструкции

```
HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen(
 TEXT("WinInet Test"),
 INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,
 NULL,
 NULL,
 0);
```

возникает ошибка:

> Unresolved external 'InternrtOpenA' referensed from D:...\UNIT1.OBJ

Как я понял нужно подключить библиотеку "`ws2_32.lib`".
Если ее просто добавить в проект (`Add to project`) - ничего не меняется.
Если добавить через "`#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")`" (я ее даже в папку проекта скопировал) тоже ничего не меняется.

Что еще можно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) реализация `InternetOpen` находится в библиотеке **wininet.lib(dll)**, а вовсе не в ws2_32.lib.

Comment: Методом тыка, я это выяснил. Но, как ни странно, в различных примерах видел, что подключается именно ws2_32.lib.
Интересно, это может быть связано со средой разработки? У борланда своя, у студии своя?